# Centos 7 with 2 network interfaces on same network one of them doesn't respond to ping from outside

Tags: linux, networking

I have a centos7 just installed with 2 active interfaces on the same network like this
ip addr show

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:1e:50:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 213.78.236.190/26 brd 213.78.236.191 scope global eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42a8:f0ff:fe1e:5054/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:1e:50:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
4: eno3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:1e:50:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 213.78.236.175/26 brd 213.78.236.191 scope global eno3
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42a8:f0ff:fe1e:5056/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: eno4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 40:a8:f0:1e:50:57 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

routing table looks like this
ip route show

```
default via 213.78.236.129 dev eno1
213.78.236.128/26 dev eno1  proto kernel  scope link  src 213.78.236.190
213.78.236.128/26 dev eno3  proto kernel  scope link  src 213.78.236.175
```

the problem is that i have access only to the interface with 213.78.236.190 from the outside world ie another network. I can ping-it, connect to ssh do whatever. But on the 213.78.236.175 i can only connect from local network. It doesn't respond to ping from outside i can see the packets coming on tcpdump but no response.

iptables is clean

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I know that this should work because this replaces a centos6 with similar configuration and on centos 6 worked from the start just config the ip on both interfaces and the default gw on one interface. 
I disabled NetworkManager i suspected he was messing something up. I enabled ip_forwarding in sysctl.conf

```
cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
1
```

even if i don't think i need to.
I can see the icmp packets coming from outside in tcpdump but nothing goes out. Below is what happens if i ping from the machine 213.65.165.84. The ip i am pinging is 213.78.236.175

```
tcpdump -i eno3 -n -p| grep ICMP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:52:09.531494 IP 213.65.165.84 > 213.78.236.175: ICMP echo request, id 16686, seq 23, length 64
10:52:10.531489 IP 213.65.165.84 > 213.78.236.175: ICMP echo request, id 16686, seq 24, length 64
10:52:11.531492 IP 213.65.165.84 > 213.78.236.175: ICMP echo request, id 16686, seq 25, length 64
10:52:12.531483 IP 213.65.165.84 > 213.78.236.175: ICMP echo request, id 16686, seq 26, length 64

tcpdump -i eno1 -n -p| grep ICMP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
```

and this is what happens if i ping the other ip 213.78.236.190 from the same machine

```
tcpdump -i eno1 -n -p| grep ICMP
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eno1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
10:58:45.973485 IP 213.65.165.84 > 213.78.236.190: ICMP echo request, id 16705, seq 5, length 64
10:58:45.973522 IP 213.78.236.190 > 213.65.165.84: ICMP echo reply, id 16705, seq 5, length 64
10:58:46.973483 IP 213.65.165.84 > 213.78.236.190: ICMP echo request, id 16705, seq 6, length 64
10:58:46.973515 IP 213.78.236.190 > 213.65.165.84: ICMP echo reply, id 16705, seq 6, length 64
```

After kasperd observed i updated the post with tcpdump with -p option to prevent promiscuous mode and checked in wireshark to see that the ping requests arrive with the correct mac address. So the problem seems to be that the kernel drops the packets for some reason.

Comment: What happens on the other interface? Replies are not necessarily send over the same interface that the requests were received.

Comment: i have edited to show what happens in tcpdump on both interfaces.

Comment: A few things: It is better to use the filtering capabilities in `tcpdump` than passing the output through `grep`. And it is better to exclude those packets you know are of no interest instead of only showing those you think are relevant. For example what about ARP packets. Also the two traces in the first case are not covering the same time interval. Apparently you are receiving copies of the packets on both interfaces, so far that is the only real clue we got on what might be going wrong.

Comment: as mentioned below that is because i didn't run tcpdump with the -p option.

Answer (score 1):

Though you mentioned that iptables was clean, you mentioned that you just recently installed CentOS 7, so I was wondering if the default firewall software for CentOS 7, firewalld, is active and, if so, whether it is blocking ICMP echo replies for one of its zones. E.g., if firewalld is active, for its GUI, running firewall-config and checking "ICMP Filter" for each zone would show if there are any filters for "echo-request" and "echo-reply". If it was blocking them, you could still see the echo requests with tcpdump. You could also check using  "firewall-cmd --list-all-zones", looking for the "icmp-blocks" line for each zone.

Comment: As shown in the post the firewall is not active iptables is clean. Initially it was but i disabled the firewall and cleaned the iptables content.

Answer (score 1):

Issue is a change with RHEL 6 and up and the rp_filter settings where changed in kernel.
Look at http://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031

Answer (score 0):

I can think of one explanation that matches all of the symptoms described so far. On the router a static ARP entry has been configured mapping that IP address to the MAC address of the interface on your old server.

When packets arrive from the outside, the router does not send any ARP request because it already has an entry for that IP address.

The switch upon receiving the packets will look for the destination MAC address in its CAM, but won't find it because the old server with that MAC address is no longer on this network. The switch will thus broadcast the packets on all interfaces (except from the one it got the packet from).

When you run tcpdump on the server, the interface is by default switched to promiscuous mode. In promiscuous mode all packets are shown, even if their destination address are not matching. If you used the `-p` flag for tcpdump, the network interface would ignore these packets and not send them to the kernel.

The kernel does deliver the packets to tcpdump, but the IP stack is not processing them due to the wrong destination MAC address.

When instead sending an echo request from another host on the LAN, the ARP entry on the router does not affect anything. The other host will send an ARP request, and your server will send an ARP response. In those cases the echo requests will be send to the correct MAC address. So the echo requests will only be seen by the correct interface, and as the destination MAC address is correct, the IP stack will process those packets.

Comment: This is not the case because this happens even if i switch the default gw interface. And i have just run tcpdump with -p and i do receive the requests on eno3 and i don't receive them on eno1 so the arp is ok on the router.

Comment: @ZR If the router did send the packets to a MAC address known to the switch, then you wouldn't see the packets on the other interface, not even when configured in promiscuous mode. You need a dump in which you can see the source and destination MAC address of the packets as well as both the ARP and ICMP packets. I am not sure if you can get tcpdump to show the MAC address, but using `-Uw filename` will allow you to dump the packets to a file which can be viewed in other tools such as Ethereal.

Comment: I have checked in ethereal(wireshark) the dump and the ping to 213.78.236.175 does come with the correct mac address 40:a8:f0:1e:50:56. I have checked both active interfaces tcpdump -i eno3 -n -p -Uw dump3, tcpdump -i eno1 -n -p -Uw dump1 and found the requests in dump3 and no reply in dump1 or in dump3

Comment: @ZR That leaves open the question about why the packet is seen on both interfaces when capturing in promiscuous mode. Somehow the switch appears to not know the address. Which MAC address do you see on request and reply, when the request arrives from the LAN? And what does ARP request and reply look like in each case?

Comment: it was only seen on both interfaces when the interface was in promiscuous mode after i used the -p option i didn't see the package on both interfaces.

Comment: @ZR The switch is still sending it to both interfaces, that's not supposed to happen. If the switch was only sending the packet to the correct interface, the other interface wouldn't see it.